# Regarding MATLAB slice function

Tags: matlab, slice

[image: slice]

This image represents my 3D array shown by using 'slice' function

My question is:

- As you can see from the image, there are 8 images in my 3D array (1mm~8mm)

however, each picture actually represents damage at 0 mm (surface) to 7 mm (z-axis)

**So, how do I make z-axis value 0 to 7? instead of 1 to 8?**

In the image I attached, you see 0 mm because I set:

```
    zlim([0 8])
```

However, there are still 8 images corresponding to 1mm to 8mm

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the slice documentation:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2,-2:.25:2,-2:.16:2);
v = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2-z.^2);
xslice = [-1.2,.8,2]; 
yslice = 2; 
zslice = [-2,0];
slice(x,y,z,v,xslice,yslice,zslice)
colormap hsv
```

You can pass the coordinate system as the first three arguments to slice, then express the slice locations in this coordinate system, so in your case:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(0:100,0:100,0:7);
slice(x,y,z,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

Where you'd express zslice in the range [0,7] when defining your desired slice locations.